# Problem with utf8 encoding Java strings using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have written a program that sends a request to the Yahoo API in several natural languages. The encoding on Yahoo has to be utf8. No problem in Delphi or Perl. In my Java version, I convert the search query sQuery1 like this:
 try{
   utf8Bytes = sQuery1.getBytes("utf-8");
   sQuery8 = new String(utf8Bytes, "utf-8");
      } catch (etc.)
Works fine when compiled from the command line. But when I type exactly the same code with Netbeans and run the jar, the Yahoo server sends an error message each time I use special characters like French accents (works fine for English though). Apparently, the jar compiled with Netbeans doesn't take the utf8 conversion into account. When run from Netbeans itself, the program works fine. Any explanation?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of your jar file?

Answer (score 2):

I have a batch file to call my jar. As soon as I have changed it like below, everything worked like a charm:

> java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar MultiLangugePain.jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as I checked Clean and Build Main Project in Netbeans and then ran the jar file created in the dist folder.

Comment: very similar problem here. will inform as soon as I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Java String is in UTF-16